# Analytic function problem from Bak, Newman- Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working through the problems in Bak, Newman as self-study and this question doesn't have a solution in the back of the book, nor do I know how to solve adequately solve it.

[image]

For a.,  my thought was tat both the numerator and denominator are analytic as they are polynomials. Then by using the exponential definition of a complex number, show the points in the map are in the unit circle. But, I can't get this to work.

For b., it seems stating that f is holomorphic and the domain is bounded and using the maximum modulus theorem is sufficient.

I feel I have the general ideas, but cannot manage to put them together into complete proofs.

Comment: Post the problem here, not a link, which may disappear over time.

Comment: @zhw. It is the problem. I uploaded a photo, it's not a link.

Answer (score 1):

Once you plug in $z=Re^{i\theta}$ factor an $e^{i\theta}$ out of the denomenator.  What is left is a complex number divided by it's conjugate.  This should have magnitude of 1 and thus is on the unit circle.